# Neo4j: Unable to lock store

Tags: graph, locking, neo4j

I'm using Neo4j graph DB and viewing the data on the browser. So whenever I run a code, i need to change database location field in  neo4j-server.properties file.

When i try to access DB with browser on I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to lock store
[<DB path>], this is usually a result of some other Neo4j kernel running using
the same store.
```

Is it possible to view the database without locking the store?

Comment: Your java program starts another one instance of your database and browser another. So there are two states running for the same db, hence the lock issue. Looking into their docs(http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/), there is no method to work with an existing instance. So I don't think there is a way to have more locks. But in this link (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/neo4j/neo4j_native_java_api_example.htm), in the very end the note says that "Ne04J DBA people will update DB properties to allow some number of locks at a time", so there might be something in the conf files too.

Answer (score 3):

There is another process using the db.  For instance, you opened it with another program (e.g. a gremlin shell in a terminal) or there is another neo4j instance running.

If you are using a Unix-like system (Linux, MacOSX, etc.), then you can use lsof to determine the processes that have opened your db.  For instance, if the path to my db is `/home/user/db/myneo4j.db`, then I would search for:

```
$ lsof /home/user/db/myneo4j.db/neostore.propertystore.db.index
```

Or you can just try:

```
$ lsof | grep myneo4j.db
```

That will tell you the process ID that has taken (locked) the database.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure no java process is running against the datastore before you start the neo4j server to view your data?