# ETL talend to neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to import data from .ods file to neo4j. But my talend job is giving following error

```
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3842
[statistics] connected
Exception in component tNeo4jConnection_1
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@786c730' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:252)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:86)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:74)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59)
    at importdata.dataimport_0_1.DataImport.tNeo4jConnection_1Process(DataImport.java:304)
    at importdata.dataimport_0_1.DataImport.runJobInTOS(DataImport.java:1135)
    at importdata.dataimport_0_1.DataImport.main(DataImport.java:1001)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@786c730' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:495)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:105)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:239)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@73da669c' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:495)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:105)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.start(XaDataSourceManager.java:131)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:489)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to lock store [D:\Softwares\neo4j-community-1.9.1-windows\neo4j-community-1.9.1\data\graph.db\neostore], this is usually a result of some other Neo4j kernel running using the same store.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.CommonAbstractStore.checkStorage(CommonAbstractStore.java:178)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.CommonAbstractStore.<init>(CommonAbstractStore.java:119)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.AbstractStore.<init>(AbstractStore.java:80)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.NeoStore.<init>(NeoStore.java:88)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFactory.attemptNewNeoStore(StoreFactory.java:106)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFactory.newNeoStore(StoreFactory.java:95)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.start(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:244)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:489)
    ... 11 more
```

Any idea??

Answer (score 1):

This normally happens when you have two different processes trying to access the same database. Each process holds the lock of the db. When other process tries accessing it, it needs to release the lock.

If on linux, you can know the process accessing it from `lsof` command (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309266/neo4j-unable-to-lock-store)).