# Unable to lock store [?], this is usually caused by another Neo4j kernel already running in this JVM for this particular store

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Exception on Spring neo4j application

Exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'graphDatabaseService': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to lock store [/var/bites/db/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names], this is usually caused by another Neo4j kernel already running in this JVM for this particular store
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:285)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1077)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:981)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:636)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:602)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:521)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:462)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4914)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5201)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to lock store [/var/bites/db/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names], this is usually caused by another Neo4j kernel already running in this JVM for this particular store
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:277)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to lock store [/var/bites/db/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names], this is usually caused by another Neo4j kernel already running in this JVM for this particular store
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.CommonAbstractStore.checkStorage(CommonAbstractStore.java:191)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.CommonAbstractStore.<init>(CommonAbstractStore.java:119)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.AbstractDynamicStore.<init>(AbstractDynamicStore.java:71)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.DynamicStringStore.<init>(DynamicStringStore.java:47)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFactory.newDynamicStringStore(StoreFactory.java:111)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFactory.newRelationshipTypeStore(StoreFactory.java:117)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFactory.attemptNewNeoStore(StoreFactory.java:93)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFactory.newNeoStore(StoreFactory.java:82)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.<init>(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:232)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.create(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:423)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:226)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:79)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:70)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
    ... 32 more
```

My Context:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
    <neo4j:config storeDirectory="/var/bites/db/"
        base-package="br.com.bites.dashboard.model.gnip" id="bites" />
    <neo4j:repositories base-package="br.com.bites.dashboard.repo.gnip" />

</beans>
```

Comment: Would you like help formatting, or not?

Comment: Have you had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309266/neo4j-unable-to-lock-store?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22694563/unable-to-obtain-lock-on-store-lock-file